# in plotly show text by default for map when saving to image

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox

I have created a plotly map and added some lat, lon points on it with marker and text and it shows fine when viewed as interactive map on Jupyter notebook but when I'm saving that map as PNG text doesn't show.
here is my code

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

mapbox_access_token = open(".mapbox_token").read()

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=['45.5017'],
        lon=['-73.5673'],
        mode='markers',
        marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
            size=14
        ),
        text=['Montreal'],
    ))

fig.update_layout(
    hovermode='closest',
    mapbox=dict(
        accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
        bearing=0,
        center=go.layout.mapbox.Center(
            lat=45,
            lon=-73
        ),
        pitch=0,
        zoom=5
    )
)

fig.show()
```

**Expected output**
[image: expected output image]

**Output I get when image is saved**
[image: output i get when image is saved]

i just want all text/annotation visible after saving image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hover function can be enabled by moving the mouse cursor closer. So if you want to save a graph, that information will not be saved. If you add text information to the map as annotations, it will be saved in the image. The position, text color, font family, and size are specified for the annotation. The display format can be standardized by using texttemplate.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

mapbox_access_token = open("mapbox_api_key.txt").read()

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
    lat=['45.5017'],
    lon=['-73.5673'],
    mode='markers+text',
    marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
        size=14
        ),
    text=['Montreal'],
    textfont={'color':'royalblue', 'family':'Arial','size':16},
    textposition='bottom right', 
    texttemplate='(%{lat},%{lon})%{text}'
    )) 

fig.update_layout(
    hovermode='closest',
    mapbox=dict(
        accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
        bearing=0,
        center=go.layout.mapbox.Center(
            lat=45,
            lon=-73
        ),
        pitch=0,
        zoom=5
    )
)

fig.show()
```

[image]