# plotly scattermapbox as solid label

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to place solid labels above choropleth_mapbox layer. I'm using add_scattermapbox, but still got only hover label as result.

only marker is visible, text appears on hover

[image: only marker is visible, text appears on hover]

```
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(
        data,
        geojson=geojson,
        color="typ",
        locations="par_id",
        # TODO u novejsi verze uz neni featureidkey
        featureidkey="properties.par_id",
        center=center,
        zoom=zoom,
        opacity=0.1,
        color_discrete_map={
            "poptávaná": "#CB4B41",
            "nepoptávaná": "#E4E4A1",
            "v kú": "#E4E4A1"
        })

    fig.update_layout(
        margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0},
        height=800,
        showlegend=False,
        mapbox_style="white-bg",
        mapbox_layers=[
            {
                "below": 'traces',
                "sourcetype": "raster",
                "sourceattribution": "CUZK",
                "source": [
                    url_ags_orto
                ],
                "visible": layer_visibility['orto']
            },
            {
                "below": 'traces',
                "sourcetype": "raster",
                "sourceattribution": "CUZK",
                "source": [
                    url_ags_zm
                ],
                "visible": layer_visibility['zm']
            },
            {
                "below": 'traces',
                "sourcetype": "raster",
                "sourceattribution": "CUZK",
                "source": [
                    kn_wms_url
                ],
                "visible": layer_visibility['kn']
            },
            {
                "below": 'traces',
                "color": "#aaff77",
                "fill": {
                  "outlinecolor": "#66ff33"
                },
                "sourcetype": "vector",
                "sourceattribution": "LPIS",
                "source": [
                    url_vt_lpis
                ],
                "sourcelayer": "lpis_pudni_bloky_vt-c3c011",
                "type": "fill",
                "visible": layer_visibility['lpis'],
                "opacity": 0.25
            },
            #tady vykreslovat border pod jednou vrstvou
            {
                "color": "#ff5233",
                "type": "fill",
                "fill": {
                  "outlinecolor": "#ff5233"
                },
                "sourcetype": "geojson",
                "source": par_selection_geojson,
                "opacity": 0.3
            },
            {
                "color": "#ff5233",
                "type": "line",
                "sourcetype": "geojson",
                "source": par_selection_geojson
            }
        ])

    gdf_labels = (
        gpd
            .GeoDataFrame(
                data,
                geometry=gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(data['geom_4326'])
                )   
            .assign(
                lat=lambda df: df.geometry.centroid.y,
                lon=lambda df: df.geometry.centroid.x
            )        
        )

    fig.add_scattermapbox(
            lat=gdf_labels.lat,
            lon=gdf_labels.lon,
            text=gdf_labels.par_cislo,
            textfont={"color":"white","size":20, "family":"Courier New"},
            mode="text",
            texttemplate='%{gdf_labels.par_cislo}'
        )
```

I possibly cover the labels by one of mapbox_layers in fig.update_layout, but can't find out how to get rid of it.

another clue can be unkown [style](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4110), but I don't know, where I should place "glyph" in python

Comment: Are my past [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68826717/in-plotly-show-text-by-default-for-map-when-saving-to-image) what you are looking for?

Comment: unfortunatelly not :(